# How to get the response from nock

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, http, nock

I've been writing some unit tests and I noticed that I can't seem to find a good way to test asynchronous functions. So I found nock. It seems cool, only if it worked. I'm clearly missing something...

```
import nock from 'nock';
import request from 'request';

const profile = {
    name: 'John',
    age: 25
};

const scope = nock('https://mydomainname.local')
    .post('/api/send-profile', profile)
    .reply(200, {status:200});

request('https://mydomainname.local/api/send-profile').on('response', function(request) {
    console.log(typeof request.statusCode); // this never hits
    expect(request.statusCode).to.equal.(200);
});
```

`request` never happens, so how can I test if nock actually returned `{status:200}`? I've also tried `fetch` and regular `http` calls. Which makes me think it's something with my nock code? Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nock does not return `{status:200}` because it's intercepting `POST` request, but the `request` statement is sending `GET` request.

It seems you want to intercept `POST` request with specified `profile`? The code would be:

```
var nock = require('nock');
var request = require('request');

const profile = {
  name: 'John',
  age: 25
};

const scope = nock('https://mydomainname.local')
  .post('/api/send-profile', profile)
  .reply(200, {status:200});

request.post('https://mydomainname.local/api/send-profile', {json: {name: 'John', age: 25}}).on('response', function(request) {
  console.log(request.statusCode); // 200
});
```